# Event detect when shutdown or restart windows 8

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, application-shutdown, application-restart

I'm working on windows 8 metro style app. I want to show a save confirmation message whenever unexpected events occur such as shutdown or restart and prevent windows to do that event. However, I didn't find any handler event that fitting my need. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, a Windows app can prevent shutdown (sometimes) by responding with FALSE to a [WM_QUERYENDSESSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.  However, there is no way to get a [WindowProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message from a Metro style app.  The best you can do in a Metro style app is [handle the Suspending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx) event properly in your app (this will not prevent a shutdown of course).

Comment: It should be noted that you need to handle the save state better anyway -- you can be terminated any time you are switched away, not just on shutdown.